# How many "Mos Eisley-like" settlements are there on Tatooine?

Tags: star-wars, tatooine

I know that Mos Eisley and Mos Espa were the first and most important cities on the planet Tatooine, but in the game [*Star Wars: The Old Republic*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Old_Republic) a lot of other "Mos-like" settlements appeared (Mos Ila, Mos Taike, Mos Gamos, Mos Anek etc).

What other settlements are there (canon), and where are they located (also canon)?

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tatooine

Comment: Mentions from the film include Tosche Station, Anchorhead, Whereveryouregoing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Canon sources, there are several settlements that fit the "Mos -" naming convention other than the two which appear in the films:

- Mos Doba, which appears in the 2014 mobile game *Star Wars Commander*. Its location is not specifically given.
- Mos Elrey, which appears in the *Star Wars: Complete Locations* reference book. It is located in the Western Dune Sea, at the edge the Jundland Wastes.
- Mos Entha, which likewise appears in *Star Wars: Complete Locations*. It is located "across from" the Mospic High Range, a mountain range between Mos Espa and the Dune Sea.
- Mos Pelgo, which appears most prominently in *The Mandalorian*, which is only specified as being in the northern hemisphere of the planet.
- Mos Taike, another place appearing almost exclusively in *Star Wars: Complete Locations*. It is located on the edge of the Northern Dune Sea.

and last and certainly least,

- Mos Zabu, a place mentioned only in episode 3 of *Star Wars: Jedi Temple Challenge*, a children's game show on [StarWarsKids.com](https://starwarskids.com).

There are, of course, settlements on Tatooine that do not fit the "Mos- " naming convention, but that is outside the scope of your question.

Comment: According to *which* canon sources?

Comment: I mention each source as I list the locations.

Comment: I meant for the non-Mos settlements.

Comment: Well there's two mentioned in ANH, Anchorhead and Tosche Station, and one mentioned in _Complete Locations_, Bestine.

Comment: Isn't Bestine a planet?

Comment: @IG_42 Two different places can have the same name.